# Displaying address / location in Bing map which is embedded in website

Tags: html, web, embed, bing-maps, pushpin

I am trying to add my business location in the Find-us page in my website. I have tried using the `Share this Map` option to obtain the HTML source code.

I have the following **HTML Code**:

```
<div id="mapviewer">
<iframe id="map" scrolling="no" width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" src="http://www.bing.com/maps/embed/?v=2&amp;cp=51.539516~0.078122&amp;lvl=15&amp;dir=0&amp;sty=r&amp;eo=0&amp;q=IG11%208FG&amp;form=LMLTEW&amp;emid=8cd3a6a7-a0a0-d941-0120-307b10dac26f">
</iframe><div id="LME_maplinks" style="line-height:20px;">
<a id="LME_largerMap" href="http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&amp;cp=51.539516~0.078122&amp;lvl=15&amp;dir=0&amp;sty=r&amp;eo=0&amp;q=IG11%208FG&amp;form=LMLTEW" target="_blank" style="margin:0 7px">View Larger Map</a>
<a id="LME_directions" href="http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&amp;cp=51.539516~0.078122&amp;lvl=15&amp;dir=0&amp;sty=r&amp;eo=0&amp;q=IG11%208FG&amp;form=LMLTEW&amp;rtp=%7Epos.51.53951644897461_0.0781221166253232_London" target="_blank" style="margin:0 7px">Driving Directions</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Presently, all I can see is a narrowed down map showing vague details about the location. 
I would like to have a black overlay with the address / location which can be seen in bing maps or a puspin or {anything else} that can pinpoint where my business is located. 
I tried adding a where1=... parameter to the source (I read in an article), but that didn't work.

Comment: Where do you need the Pin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a pushpin when you generate the code in Bing. On the "Customise and Preview" dialog, you are able to right-click and add a pushpin. Why not do this where you need it to be placed?

Comment: I was looking for a bit more sophisticated push pin just like the one that is visible on bing maps, the black callout overlay with the name of the business but anyway the blue dot(pushpin) should suffice. Thank you.

Comment: I think your post partially answers his question (or maybe I'm just missing something). You DON'T get an address tooltip above the pushpin, you only get the pushpin which in my opinion ain't very helpful. Is there maybe a way to add the tooltip as well ?